# how to get data when using where clause of time stamp in select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I’m trying to get date with select query that have time stamp in WHERE clause.

my data table look like this:

```
| startTime  |  endTime    | TimeID 
----------------------------------
| 07:00:00   |  15:00:00   |   1 
| 15:00:00   |  23:00:00   |   2
| 23:00:00   |  07:00:00   |   3
---------------------------------
```

this is  my query statement:

```
SELECT  TimeID
FROM    myTable
WHERE   StartTime >= 'Current_TIME' AND EndTime < 'Current_TIME'
```

if the time is somewhere between 07:00 and 23:00 then I get the answer correct, else I don't.

for example:

if the current time is 02:00:00 then the first condition is false because 02 is not larger then 23 and second condition is valid >  02 is smaller then 07

I try to use BETWEEN clause and use CASE WHEN and ISNULL but the query always returns empty in the scenario above.

Comment: Is it possible to split the row that goes over midnight into 2 separate rows?

Comment: The best solution would be use the time datatype instead of trying to compare string values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, but it's not the best in performance wise:

```
SELECT  TimeID
FROM    myTable
WHERE   
(
  (StartTime <= 'Current_TIME' AND EndTime > 'Current_TIME') or
  (StartTime <= 'Current_TIME' AND StartTime > EndTime) or
  (EndTime   >  'Current_TIME' AND StartTime > EndTime)
)
```

It would probably be better to split the row that spans midnight into 2 separate rows, if possible.

Comment: thanks, this solution is great, i cannot split the midnight to 2 separate rows